# Tortoise git commit not working for Multiple repositories

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have enabled multiple remote Git repositories for my project **origin** and **upstream**

[image: Multiple Remote Repo]

Post making changes to a file. I am trying to commit it. Changes are getting pushed to only **origin** repo.

[image: Git commit]

How do I push changes to multiple repo using single commit

**Note** : Connection to ***upstream*** are working fine. If I do a manual push to ***upstream*** then changes are getting pushed over there.

Answer (score 0):

Try and switch first to command line, where you can execute, in the folder of your local repository:

```
git remote add all ssh://localhost:8001/MySpace/sss
git remote set-url --add --push all /remote/url/for/upstream
```

Then close/reopen Tortoise for Git, and see if by pushing to "`all`", you would push both to `origin` and `upstream` URLs.

Comment: standalone push is working and pushing to both origin & upstream repo.  While commiting when we select  **Commit & Push** . That push is only pushing to origin repo.

Comment: @ChennaiCheetah Yes, because Tortoise would push by default to origin. If you rename "all" as "origin", Tortoise would push to both.